# How to convert a list of a list to be columns in a dataframe with an index?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

So essentially I have a list of list for example:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
     [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]
```

So each list has 10 numbers inside of it.I have an index list for example:

```
index = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
```

I want to create a python dataframe to be structured as the following:

```
 A  1  11
 B  2  12
 C  3  13
 D  4  14 
 E  5  15
 F  6  16
 G  7  17 
 H  8  18
 I  9  19 
 J  10 20
```

Basically turning each list in a to be a column in the dataframe.

I tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = a, index = index)
```

It ran but the lists didn't turn into the columns instead they were still the rows. Any easy way of doing this?

Comment: FYI: python 2.7 is at [end of life](https://pythonclock.org)

Comment: `df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, index=index) for x in a], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
a = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
     [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]

index = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

pd.DataFrame(a, columns=index).T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
     [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]

index = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

data = {f'col_{i}': column for i, column in enumerate(a)}

pd.DataFrame(data, index = index)
```

Convert the list of lists into a dictionary, with the column name being the key and the list to be used as a column the value. Pass that dictionary to the `pd.DataFrame` function to get the following output:

```
col_0   col_1
A   1   11
B   2   12
C   3   13
D   4   14
E   5   15
F   6   16
G   7   17
H   8   18
I   9   19
J   10  20
```